# Assistance with customizing data output while using AlphaVantage API in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, alpha-vantage

I am working on putting together a bunch of historical stock data for a project, and Alpha Vantage seemed like the best service for that. I'm using their Alpha Vantage Google Sheets Add-On. Everything is configured properly and pumping out the correct data, but it's not pumping out data in the format I want.

So for example let's say I use the following formula: =AVGetTechnicalIndicator("T", "MACD", "daily",H5480:I5481) I will get the following result, wherein the date goes all the way back to 1999/2000: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-ZGJmWCnUJnugutUKTeYn4QIszTZfDA/view?usp=sharing

So as you can see, with just using the formula as is, it prints the date from most recent descending, and the matching indicator data.

However, I want the data to print like in the following image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBCAStD15y3eV3srcBBF6tKEnj4gIsoL/view?usp=sharing

So I want to compile several technical indicators into the same table for the same stock, and I just want one date column, and then a SMA, EMA, OBV, etc. columns, and I want all of this to be automated so it will fetch the most recent data daily and add it to the table.

So I have three questions:

1.) How can I do this without ending up with several date columns?

2.) How can I get the data to output so the oldest date is at the top, instead of the most recent date at the top?

3.) How can I choose a date range? For example, I only want data starting in January 2008 to the present.

Thank you very much for any assistance you can provide.

I also posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/u0ka6g/assistance_with_customizing_data_output_while/

Comment: Please cross post a link here and on your Reddit post with links to the other

Comment: Hi there @drew! Those operations could be run easily using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Would that be a valid answer for you?